# Explain out of this code?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I'm new to programming. I can't find out the reason as to why the output is
`0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55`

Shouldn't it be `0 1 1 3 5 7` etc?

First, `i=0` so prints `0 (because return 0)`, second `i=1` so prints `1 (because return 1)`, third `i=2` so prints `1 because (2-1)+(2-2)=1`, fourth `i=3` so prints `3 because (3-1)+(3-2)=3` etc..

Forgive me for this very basic question. Maybe programming is not for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define MAX 10

    int i=12345;
    double y=1.23456;

    void display_variables()
    {
      double y=4.352;
      printf("i=%d, y=%f\n", i,y);
    }

    int main()
    {
        printf("i=%d, y=%f\n", i,y);
        display_variables();
        int c,i=0;  
        for (c = 0; c <= MAX; c++)
            {
                printf("%d\n", fib(i));
            i++;
            }
        return 0;
        } 

    int fib(int n)
    {
       if ( n == 0 )
          return 0;
       else if ( n == 1 )
          return 1;
       else
          return ( fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) );
    }
```

Comment: But it's not `(3-1) + (3-2)` is it?! It's `fib(3-1) + fib(3-2)`.

Comment: Do not desperate, programming is fun! C++ is not the easiest language either! Good learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently，

```
fib(0) = 0,
fib(1) = 1,
fib(2) = fib(1) + fib(0)  = 1,
fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1)
       = fib(1) + fib(0) + fib(1)
       = 1 + 0 + 1
       = 2
etc...
```

Everyone make mistakes， especially starting to the new, you need to be patient, you'll find the interest

Comment: Thanks!! i understand how it goes now!! So you sorta backtrack and use the result from the last equations to plug it into the next ones :))